# Python txt file- Reading and using information in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have a txt file with the general form:

```
Last Name
First Name
Year
Medal (This line only contains one number either 1,2,3 meaning gold,silver,bronze respectively)
```

What I'm trying to do is have the user input a year and count how many medals were won for that year. then have another function where the user can input a first and last name, the function should print out "john smith won a gold(1) medal in 1864"

```
def medals(medalcount):
    year= str(input("Please enter a year: "))
    with open("textfile") as f:
          medalcount+=f.read().count(year)
    return medalcount
```

Basically I'm using this function to count how many times the string year entered by the user appears in the txt file.
As for the next part I'm still kind of confused on how to actually approach it.

Example:

```
Smith
John
1896
1
```

```
>>> Please enter year: 1896
15 medals won in this year
```

Comment: Can you give an example input? Your description confuses me.

Comment: Right now your textfile example looks as if you've got one file per person per year. Is that right? Do you not mean a file with multiple such listings?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was only showing how the entire file looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def readFile(infilepath):
    answer = {}
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for lastname in infile:
            lastname = lastname.strip()
            firstname = infile.readline().strip()
            year = infile.readline().strip()
            medal = infile.readline().strip()

            if year not in answer:
                answer[year] = {}
            if lastname not in answer[year]:
                answer[year][lastname] = {}
            if firstname not in answer[year][lastname]:
                answer[year][lastname][firstname] = {}
            if medal not in answer[year][lastname][firstname]:
                answer[year][lastname][firstname][medal] = 0
            answer[year][lastname][firstname][medal] += 1
    return answer

def count(medalcounts):
    year = input("What year would you like to check: ").strip()
    answer = 0
    for lastname in medalcounts[year]:
        for firstname,medals in medalcounts[year][lastname].items():
            answer += sum(medals.values())
    print(answer, "medals were awarded in", year)

    firstname = input("Enter first name: ").strip()
    lastname = input("Enter last name: ").strip()
    for year,yeard in medalcounts.items():
        medals = yeard[lastname][firstname]
        for med,count in medals.items():
            print("In year", year, firstname, lastname, "won", count, '. gold silver bronze'.split()[med], "medals")
```

USAGE:

```
count(readFile('path/to/file'))
```

Comment: I see that def count is not calling def readFile at any point, how does it do all the check work?

Comment: also what does .items do

Comment: @Cos: `myDict.items()` gives you a list of key,value pairs of `myDict`